# Auto call text box when cell is selected in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I want when I select a cell in Column B to be connected automatically in the text box
And I created a code that does not work automatically
Asking, I want to make this code automatic without pressing the button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   With Me
 
       .TextBox1.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Value
     
   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Selection Change Changing Text Box Value

- Put the following into the sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`) of the worksheet where the text box is located.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const sCol As String = "B"
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(Columns("B"), Target)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        TextBox1.Value = rg.Cells(1).Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I thank you very much, my friend
The problem has been resolved
This code works fine
I wish I could vote for you
But I cannot due to site restrictions

Comment: @FathyAhmed Even despite of reputation less 15 (allowing you to upvote) you are in the position to accept a solution by ticking the green checkmark left to the answer :-)